# Getting a Matrix from a file and assigning it to an array with a max size

Tags: c++, arrays, file, matrix

Okay, so i have an array `a[maxsize] [maxsize]` where `maxsize=10` how do i get an array to work correctly when taking an array from a file that is smaller than the max size.

Example matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Is coming out:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

My code:
`int main()
{
    const int maxsize = 10;
    double original_matrix[maxsize][maxsize], transposed_matrix[maxsize][maxsize];

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

fin.open ("input.txt");

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
    return 0;
}

for(i=0; i<maxsize; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<maxsize; j++)
    {
        fin >> original_matrix [i][j];
    }
}

transpose(original_matrix[][maxsize], transposed_matrix[][maxsize],maxsize)


return 0;
}
```

I want the array to assign it like this

```
M [0] [0]=1 M [0] [1]=2 M [0] [2]=3
M [1] [0]=4 M [1] [1]=5 M [1] [2]=6
M [2] [0]=7 M [2] [1]=8 M [2] [2]=9
```

Not

```
M [0] [0]=1 M [0] [1]=1 M [0] [2]=1 M [0] [3]=1 M [0] [4]=1 M [0] [5]=1 M [0] [6]=1 M [0] [7]=1 M [0] [8]=1
```

..... So on

The text file looks like this:

```
2
1 0
0 1
3
8 9 1
3 5 2
-2 3 -1
0
```

Comment: You need to post some code to make this comprehensible.

Comment: @Steve Townsend - Yeah, give me a few minutes because i don't have much because i got stuck reading the matrix from the file.

Comment: You can just read them in plain into 1D array, take a square root, and use `[x + y * n]`

Comment: So do that to get the size the move to the 2d array?

Comment: What's the format of your input file?  Is each row of the matrix on its own line, or is everything on one line?

Comment: The input file is crazy weird spaces and new lines. In other words its messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the matrix to come out in matrix form, why dont you:

```
    for(i=0; i<maxsize; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<maxsize; j++)
    {
        fin >> original_matrix [i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n"
}
```

That way it comes out as a box instead of a single line.  I think you will also have to play around with maxsize, because you want it to be a matrix with no empties, so you should check how many vectors make up the matrix, and use that as a condition (instead of maxsize)

### edit - Input file psuedo code

So the first line is a single number, that tells use how many rows or columns the matrix will be. This program will assume that it is a square matrix, therefore. the condition value that you want is the first line (ie 2,3,0). Make sure to check that the value is greater than 0 and less than 10. Parse through the input line for each value, inject it into your matrix. Set the condition value, and therefore you will have a perfect square matrix.

1. Open File
2. Read line, is it the length of matrix?
         * if so, set to condition
         * if not, it is a value in the matrix
3. Check conition to make sure 0 < cond < 10
4. Print.

Comment: This may be incorrect now that I see that you edited it again.

Comment: The only catch for this is i have to use the maxsize and work off of that. So that no user can go over the size of 10X10 but can do anything under or equal to this size.

Comment: yeah, so create another condition that is upperbound by 10, i.e. int cond = 0; cond = 3 (in this case, you would grab that from how many columns there are), then do a check, if (cond > 10){ cout << "Error Matrix is too large" }, that way you can have an adjustable condition that will make sure that your matrix comes out square and does not go over the boundary of maxsize.

Comment: I'm kind of confused how to do this because the user is not entering the array it is coming from a file so it is already made.

Comment: can you edit your post and show what the textfile input looks like?